# Transferring ownership of the file using Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm creating a spreadsheet file using google drive api, then pass ownership to another email, `$automationEmail` in this case. This is how I do it:

```
$permission = $this->insertPermission($service, $file->id, $automationEmail, 'user', 'owner');
```

And this is the insertPermission function

```
function insertPermission($service, $fileId, $value, $type, $role)
{
    $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $newPermission->setEmailAddress($value);
    $newPermission->setType($type);
    $newPermission->setRole($role);
    if ($role == 'owner') {
        $permission = $service->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission, array('fields' => 'id', 'transferOwnership' => 'true'));
    } else {
        $permission = $service->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission);
    }
    if ($permission) {
        return $permission;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Until now, this used to work perfectly fine. But recently it stopped working and gives me an error: `Consent is required to transfer ownership of a file to another user.`

For other permissions,like writer or reader, everything works fine. Did anything change in the API that I could not find? I searched for the solution, but seems like noone has had this issue before, or at least I could not find anything. Why did it stop working?

Comment: @Iamblichus Hi. I implemented this functionality in our project more than one year ago and ownership transfer has been working perfectly fine. Therefore, I don't understand why it does not work anymore. Sorry, but I can't accept this answer as a solution for my problem. I'm still researching it and will send feature request if I'm not able to solve this.

Comment: @Iamblichus There is an option 'owner' in the API, so, if I can't do this, why is it there? There must be a way too. Even if ownership transfer works for the same organisation emails only, neither this makes sense too, because after creating a file, by default, the owner is Google service account, which does not belong to any organisation... Also, after getting an error, there is no notification on email to accept the ownership. Maybe there was some kind of update in the API and it's a bug that needs to be fixed?

Comment: Yes, most likely there's been a recent change in the API, considering the amount of recent reports about this. But according to Google, this is intended behavior https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227973724#comment22 (I just added this to my answer). Therefore, as I mentioned, I'd suggest you to file a feature request for this.

Comment: @Iamblichus Currently trying to learn more about this from Google support. Will submit the ticket if nothing helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring ownership directly so someone did not work, so I used the following approach: In our google workspace we enabled Domain-wide delegation for the Google service account:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account

Then I created a dedicated user for Google drive files, logged in as this user to get the access token and saved it. After that I was able to create the new files on Google Drive as this dedicated user, so the files now belong to this email by default. This is how I did it:

```
$credentials = storage_path('credentials.json');
$token = [
    'access_token'  => config('app.flex_email_access_token')
];
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Sheets');
$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Sheets::DRIVE, Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
$client->setSubject(config('app.flex_email'));
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAuthConfig($credentials);
$client->setAccessToken($token);

$serviceDrive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$body = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    "name" => [$request->name],
    'parents' => [$listing->pls_folder_id]
));

$spreadsheet = $serviceDrive->files->copy('yourspreadsheetid', $body);
```

In this example I copy the file, but the same approach works when creating them. Since the files now belong to the user I need by default, the ownership transfer issue has been avoided.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

Currently, when transfering file ownership between users who are not part of the same organization, the transfer requires the new owner to accept the invitation.

When the current owner (user #1) sets user #2 as the new owner, an invitation is sent to user #2, and user #1 remains the owner until user #2 accepts it:

> You remain the file owner until the pending owner accepts your invitation.

Since this requires the new owner to accept the invitation, the transfer cannot be done programmatically via API, so this method fails for users who don't belong to the same organization.

From Issue Tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227973724#comment22 :

> Following up here, this is the expected behavior as currently Drive does not support the changing of the ownership for items which are owned by gmail.com accounts.

#### Issue Tracker feature request:

- [API: Consent is required to transfer ownership of a file to another user](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228791253)

#### Reference:

- [Make someone else the owner of your file](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892?hl=en)